# OpenSwan tunnel not getting established with Watchguard

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipsec

I have been struggling with this issue for weeks now. First I thought it was on the Watchguard side, but seems like our side. Here is the setup:
1. EC2 instance running Amazon Linux and OpenSwan.(no iptables)
2. Other side (right side) running WatchGuard.
Tunnel does not get setup. I take the same ipsec.conf file over to a server in RackSpace running CentoS and the tunnel gets established. No idea why. I have attached the conf file and the log file if anybody can help. Thanks a lot.

```
#nual:     ipsec.conf.5
#
# Please place your own config files in /etc/ipsec.d/ ending in .conf

version 2.0 # conforms to second version of ipsec.conf specification

# basic configuration
config setup
    # Debug-logging controls:  "none" for (almost) none, "all" for lots.
    klipsdebug=all
    plutodebug=all
    # For Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Fedora, leave protostack=netkey
    protostack=netkey
    nat_traversal=yes
    #virtual_private=
    oe=off
    # Enable this if you see "failed to find any available worker"
    #nhelpers=0


#You may put your configuration (.conf) file in the "/etc/ipsec.d/" and uncomment this.

include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

/etc/ipsec.d/conn.conf

```
conn TestConn
     authby=secret
     auto=start
     forceencaps=yes
        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=209.20.92.47
        leftsourceip=209.20.92.47
        leftsubnet=10.183.128.9/32
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute

     right=50.206.18.58
     rightsubnet=10.10.2.61/32


        esp=3des-sha1
        #auth=esp
        keyexchange=ike
        ike=3des-sha1;modp1024
        #salifetime=43200s
        pfs=no
        #dpdaction=restart
        #aggrmode=no
```

Pluto Log

```
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 ipsec__plutorun: Starting Pluto subsystem...
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: nss directory plutomain: /etc/ipsec.d
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: NSS Initialized
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: Non-fips mode set in /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: Starting Pluto (Openswan Version 2.6.37; Vendor ID OEu\134d\134jy\134\134ap) pid:29440
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: Non-fips mode set in /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: LEAK_DETECTIVE support [disabled]
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: OCF support for IKE [disabled]
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: SAref support [disabled]: Protocol not available
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: SAbind support [disabled]: Protocol not available
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: NSS support [enabled]
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: HAVE_STATSD notification support not compiled in
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: Setting NAT-Traversal port-4500 floating to on
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]:    port floating activation criteria nat_t=1/port_float=1
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]:    NAT-Traversal support  [enabled]
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | inserting event EVENT_REINIT_SECRET, timeout in 3600 seconds
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | event added at head of queue
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | inserting event EVENT_PENDING_DDNS, timeout in 60 seconds
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | event added at head of queue
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | inserting event EVENT_PENDING_PHASE2, timeout in 120 seconds
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | event added after event EVENT_PENDING_DDNS
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating OAKLEY_AES_CBC: Ok (ret=0)
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: starting up 1 cryptographic helpers
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: started helper (thread) pid=140152581191424 (fd:8)
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: Using Linux 2.6 IPsec interface code on 4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 (experimental code)
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | status value returned by setting the priority of this thread (id=0) 22
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | helper 0 waiting on fd: 9
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | process 29440 listening for PF_KEY_V2 on file descriptor 12
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | finish_pfkey_msg: K_SADB_REGISTER message 1 for AH
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: |   02 07 00 02  02 00 00 00  01 00 00 00  00 73 00 00
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | pfkey_get: K_SADB_REGISTER message 1
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | AH registered with kernel.
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | finish_pfkey_msg: K_SADB_REGISTER message 2 for ESP
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: |   02 07 00 03  02 00 00 00  02 00 00 00  00 73 00 00
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | pfkey_get: K_SADB_REGISTER message 2
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | alg_init():memset(0x558361de3500, 0, 2016) memset(0x558361de3ce0, 0, 2048)
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_register_pfkey(): SADB_SATYPE_ESP: sadb_msg_len=22 sadb_supported_len=72
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_add():satype=3, exttype=14, alg_id=251
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_register_pfkey(): SADB_SATYPE_ESP: alg[0], exttype=14, satype=3, alg_id=251, alg_ivlen=0, alg_minbits=0, alg_maxbits=0, res=0, ret=1
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_add():satype=3, exttype=14, alg_id=2
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_register_pfkey(): SADB_SATYPE_ESP: alg[1], exttype=14, satype=3, alg_id=2, alg_ivlen=0, alg_minbits=128, alg_maxbits=128, res=0, ret=1
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_add():satype=3, exttype=14, alg_id=3
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_register_pfkey(): SADB_SATYPE_ESP: alg[2], exttype=14, satype=3, alg_id=3, alg_ivlen=0, alg_minbits=160, alg_maxbits=160, res=0, ret=1
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_add():satype=3, exttype=14, alg_id=5
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_register_pfkey(): SADB_SATYPE_ESP: alg[3], exttype=14, satype=3, alg_id=5, alg_ivlen=0, alg_minbits=256, alg_maxbits=256, res=0, ret=1
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_add():satype=3, exttype=14, alg_id=6
Jan 19 19:32:24 ip-10-1-201-245 pluto[29440]: | kernel_alg_register_pfkey(): SADB_SATYPE_ESP: alg[4], exttype=14, satype=3, alg_id=6, alg_ivlen=0, alg_minbits=384, alg_maxbits=384, res=0, ret=1
```

**Edit**
I could not figure out what was going on with Amazon Linux/OpenSwan. So I switched to Ubuntu Linux and with the same config file, the tunnel got establisehd in first try!! Both sides see the tunnel established. However we are not able to ping. When I ping, I see that the packets are traversing the tunnel, I see that using tcpdump. Other sides sees my packets reaching. However the reply packets are not getting to my server. I suspect something not right with AWS setup. I do have disabled the Source/Destination check on the instance, I have added a route to the subnet route table to route the packets destined to the tunnel to go to the instance running OpenSwan. Still not able to ping.

Any idea why the ping might not be working? I posted this to AWS forum also, no answers yet.   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223853&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket with AWS support. They looked at the log files and config and they gave me the answer to why the tunnel is not getting established. It was a stupid mistake from my part. The route attached to the Amazon Linux instance running OpenSwan had no route to internet, so it was not reaching the WG. Once I added that route the tunnel was established. The reason why the Ubuntu worked is because I instantiated that machine in a new Subnet which had the route to internet. So always ping the public ip of the other end first. I am impressed with the AWS support team. They know what they are doing.